# junit can't find class:***Test

Tags: junit

My classpath is defined as follows:

```
CLASSPATH:%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit.jar
JUNIT_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\junit3.8.2
```

At the cmd line, I input:

`java junit.swingui.TestRunner junit.samples.AllTests`

however, it says :

```
Class not found: junit.samples.AllTests
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ensure the classes or jar file with your test classes are on the classpath as well. Looks to me like only the java tools and junit jars are there atm.